# one to many mapping to a property of superclass

Tags: hibernate, annotations, one-to-many

I have a superclass `Questions` and its subclass `MultipleChoiceQuestions`

Superclass has a field `activity`

I want to create a `Set<MultipleChoiceQuestions>` and use `OneToMany` annotation using `mappedBy = "activity"`

e.g.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "activity" )
private Set<NQIMultipleChoiceQuestions> mcqQuestions = new HashSet<NQIMultipleChoiceQuestions>();
```

I am getting this error:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property
```

However, it works fine if I create a set of superclass entities,

e.g.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "activity")
private Set<NQIQuestions> questions = new HashSet<NQIQuestions>();
```

Is there a way to map to property of superclass?

Comment: @sahil, the two lines you showed - where you claimed that the first one did not work, but the second one did - differ only in the variable name of the `Set`.

Comment: @binil : ya.. actually in second case, questions is the base class, whereas mcqQuestion is subclass.

Comment: @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "activity")
 private Set<NQIQuestions> questions = new HashSet<NQIQuestions>();

Comment: @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "activity" )
    private Set<NQIMultipleChoiceQuestions> mcqQuestions = new HashSet<NQIMultipleChoiceQuestions>();

Comment: NQIQuestions is superclass of NQIMultipleChoiceQuestions

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Found the solution for this... :)

We can achieve this just by defining the targetEntity = ? in the OneToMany definition..

eg..

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "activity" , targetEntity=NQIQuestions.class)    
private Set<NQIMultipleChoiceQuestions> mcqQuestions = new HashSet<NQIMultipleChoiceQuestions>();
```

Comment: But doesn't the set now also include objects of other subtypes?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is true. A possible solution with Hibernate would be to use `@Where(clause="...")` with a suitable where-clause to only load the correct subtype(s).

Comment: Thanks! targetEntity just solved my problem. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you use **Hibernate and it does not support this feature** ([Hibernate ORM HHH-4233: cant bind a child using mappedby relating to a parent attribute(polymorphism)](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4233). The feature is rejected for controversial reasons. There is a comment there by Nicholas Stuart which provides more links about the subject, including this one giving some workarounds: [Chris Wong's Development Blog: Polymorphic one to many relationships in Hibernate](http://chriswongdevblog.blogspot.com/2009/10/polymorphic-one-to-many-relationships.html).

Once we know it's only Hibernate problem, we can switch to something else. **OpenJPA, EclipseLink do support it**. Please add a comment if there are more frameworks to list here.