# MappedBy reference an unknown target entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I design a system of tables in the database for the film service. So far I have designed them in this way.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movies")
@Data
public class MovieEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<MovieDescription> description;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "movies_info")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public abstract class MovieInfo {

    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    public MovieEntity movie;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = EditType.Values.DESCRIPTION)
public class MovieDescription extends MovieInfo {

    private String description;
    private String language;
}
```

When compiling, it sends me a mistake

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.core.jpa.entity.MovieDescription.movie in com.core.jpa.entity.MovieEntity.description
```

Something related to MovieEnity mapping, but I don't know what it is all about.

Comment: are you using the code first approach? if you are not, please provide the database schema

Answer (score 0):

use targetEntity attribute to target the super class field that you want to map with.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movies")
@Data
public class MovieEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(unique = true, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity= MovieInfo.class)
    private Set<MovieDescription> description;
}
```

More detail: [one to many mapping to a property of superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447613/one-to-many-mapping-to-a-property-of-superclass)